# How to correct for serial correlation in an ARDL model without increasing lags?

Tags: autocorrelation, stata, robust-standard-error, ardl

I'm currently looking to run an ARDL model - I'm able to compute results that show cointegration, however there is serial correlation when I run the Durbin-Watson and Breusch-Godfrey tests. To correct for this, I have tried to have larger lags, however this results in most of my coefficients becoming insignificant. I was wondering if there was another way to correct for this, such as using HAC standard errors?

If there is a solution e.g. HAC standard errors, how would I write it into an ARDL model on Stata?

Comment: You need not worry too much about the statistical significance of explanatory variables when building your model; see ["Statistical tests for variable selection"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tests2/) by Rob J. Hyndman.

Comment: Thank you - does that mean you would recommend increasing lags until serial correlation is eliminated?

Comment: This depends on what you are going to use your model for.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean - suppose I am finding out the effect of lagged variables on GDP growth, then is it fine to increase lags (even if this reduces significance) until I remove serial correlation?

Comment: What are you going to use your model for? Prediction? Description? Hypothesis testing? Shmueli ["To Explain or to Predict?"](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/157/Papers/shmueli.pdf) (2010) introduces some nuance into the question.

Comment: I am using my model for explanation and description i.e. mapping out relationships between key variables and which variables have a statistically significant relationship with the outcome. Is there any way I could implement HAC standard errors using the 'newey' command in Stata?

Comment: Let me reiterate my first comment. Testing for statistical significance should not be the guiding principle for building a model. Model building comes first, inference comes next. But I think you can implement HAC standard errors directly. If Stata does not support that for ARDL model (perhaps it does?), just formulate your model as a regression where lagged terms are included manually.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Testing for statistical significance should not be the guiding principle for building a model; see e.g. see [*Statistical tests for variable selection*](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tests2/) by Rob J. Hyndman. Model building comes first, inference comes next. But I think you can implement HAC standard errors directly. If Stata does not support that for ARDL model (perhaps it does?), just formulate your model as a regression where lagged terms are included manually.